# w2ui Grid with composite key database table

Tags: mysql, datagrid, w2ui

I'm using an amazing JavaScript UI library: **w2ui**. I'm learning how the *widget Grid* works.

Each row of the *Grid* is identified using a unique integer ID ([*recid*](http://w2ui.com/web/docs/w2grid.recid)). If your database has an integer as primary key this is perfect, you can use this key like *recid*. But my database table has a composite primary key, a combination of *4 columns*.

First I thought of a solution: use a hash function to generate an integer value using the 4 column values:

```
hash(idA, idB, idC, idD) = recid
```

An example of JSON returned by the server:

```
records: [
   {
      "recid": 565587,
      "key": {
         "idA": "01",
         "idB": "01",
         "idC": "1981",
         "idD": "111"
      },
      "value": 1000
   }
]
```

The *recid* is calculated at server side and used at client side to identify the grid record.

But it still isn't a solution, because when I change a cell value of the grid (I'm using [inline editing](http://w2ui.com/web/demos/#!grid/grid-21)), the widget only sends to the server the changed value and the *recid*, but *not* the composite key. So I can't identify the database table row to make the update.

Someone has a solution?

Maybe a configuration to force to send the key object to the server?

Comment: Can you modify the server code API to account for changes in recid handling?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://w2ui.com/web/docs/w2grid.save):

> Save will submit changed records. However, you can overwrite onSave
>   event and submit whatever you want with it. You can either (1) add it
>   to grid.postData object or (2) submit it yourself with $.ajax()

Looks like you have to override the default behavior to do what you want.